# Keeping a button from overlapping with text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site, still fairly new to any kind of web design.

I've got a pre-defined module that consists of several columns, each with a box that consists of a title, a text excerpt (the length is a set amount of words) and a button just below that text excerpt. Because of the variable word length the standard version of this module has different heights for each box which looks stupid.

I want to get all the boxes to the same height and set the button at the center near the bottom of the box. After trying to achieve this by setting the button to fixed positions which was horribly annoying to fine-tune, I realized I might just as well set a fixed height on the text excerpt and control the position of the button that way.

Sadly it's still not working the way I want it to. It looks great in standard view but as soon as I make my browser window smaller the leeway I gave it with the set height becomes too small (I set the height to 8em) and the button starts overlapping with the text. Due to the fact that this is a pre-defined module in a plugin I am unable to change anything about the way it's being generated, the only thing I can realistically change is adding custom CSS rules.

Pictures:

[image: Pictures]

[image: With lower screen width]

I've heard of things called clear fixes, using ::before, but when I googled them it seemed like they were only from keeping elements from scooting in from the left or the right not from above. I don't want to have to add a whole bunch of CSS rules for every element I use using @media and screen width, I'd rather have some smart way to do it. Is there one?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Vaethin When a question is asked and answered, it'd be appreciated to have a feedback or the answer rated or accepted if it solves the query.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use flexbox and I hope this gives you an idea of how you need to modify it to your use.

```css
.things {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items:flex-end;
}

.thing {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:5px;
  flex:1 0 250px;
  min-width:250px;
  max-width:300px;
  background:white;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}

.thing h3{
text-align:center;
color:red;
}

.thing small{
margin:5px;
display:block;
height:150px;
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.thing button{
margin-top:10px;
background:red;
border:2px solid white;
border-radius:5px;
flex:1 0 30px;
min-width:50px;
max-width:80px;
color:white;
height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="things">
  <div class="thing">
    <h3>AABCDEH</h3>
    <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</small>
    <button>BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    <h3>AABCDEH</h3>
    <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat., sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</small>
    <button>BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    <h3>AABCDEH</h3>
    <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</small>
    <button>BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  <div class="thing">
    <h3>AABCDEH</h3>
    <small>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</small>
    <button>BUTTON</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

just a couple options here:

I think one of the ways you can do it and have no trouble is using wp_trim_words():

```
<?php
echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );
?>
```

[Source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

But if you cannot really access even that far (can you at least read the code that lays the boxes in the page?), for sure trying a media query might help you do it nice and safe.

HTH!